# Matching Exactly all values in IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for the solution for this problem for hours now with no luck. I have a Workouts table as below. Each item in the workout table can have multiple target muscles, which are listed in the Target Muscles table.

Workouts table:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Target Muscles table:

| id | muscle_key | workout_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 4 | a | 2 |
| 5 | b | 2 |

I need to fetch all items in the workouts table which match EXACTLY ALL target muscles keys in the given set, not less and not more. For example, given the set of muscle keys:

(a,b)

The desired output would be:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |

The row for workout id = 1 should NOT be selected since it contains an extra muscle key (c).

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT id
FROM workouts
LEFT JOIN target_muscles ON workouts.id = target_muscles.workout_id
WHERE target_muscles.muscle_key IN (a,b)
GROUP BY workouts.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT target_muscles.muscle_key) = 2
```

The above query is also returning the workout id = 1, instead of only 2. How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "The row for workout id = 1 should NOT be selected"   But I do see 3 rows with workout_id=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the `WHERE` clause. Use `HAVING` to make sure exactly a and b are there.

```
SELECT workouts.id
FROM workouts
JOIN target_muscles ON workouts.id = target_muscles.workout_id
GROUP BY workouts.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT target_muscles.muscle_key) =
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN target_muscles.muscle_key IN (a,b)
                           THEN target_muscles.muscle_key END)
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT target_muscles.muscle_key) = 2
```

Can also be done as:

```
SELECT workouts.id
FROM workouts
JOIN target_muscles ON workouts.id = target_muscles.workout_id
GROUP BY workouts.id
HAVING MIN(target_muscles.muscle_key) = 'a'
   AND MAX(target_muscles.muscle_key) = 'b'
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT target_muscles.muscle_key) = 2
```

Or, perhaps less performant:

```
SELECT workouts.id
FROM workouts
JOIN (SELECT workout_id FROM target_muscles WHERE muscle_key = 'a'
      INTERSECT
      SELECT workout_id FROM target_muscles WHERE muscle_key = 'b'
      EXCEPT
      SELECT workout_id FROM target_muscles WHERE muscle_key NOT IN ('a', 'b')) dt
  ON workouts.id = dt.workout_id
```

Comment: thanks for the response. it worked. Now trying to retrieve the COUNT of the output based on the query you provided but not working. im using this query... 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT workouts.id) AS totalCount FROM workouts JOIN target_muscles ON target_muscles.workouts_id = workouts.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT target_muscles.muscle_key) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN target_muscles.muscle_key IN ('a', 'b') THEN target_muscles.muscle_key END) AND COUNT(DISTINCT target_muscles.muscle_key) = 2

Comment: @Diego The reason for the Group By is to evaluate conditions for each group. It is not possible to aggregate over the whole separately. If you have MySQL 8.0 you can get around this by restoring the group by and using SELECT COUNT(w.id) OVER() in your select statement.

Comment: @JJ32 Unfortunately my mysql version doesn't support that. I am using the length of the returned array for now, though it's less performant.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the filtering clause and use two conditions:

- count of non-(a,b) muscle_keys = 0
- distinct count of (a,b) muscle_keys = 2

```
SELECT w.id
FROM      workouts w
LEFT JOIN target_muscles ts ON w.id = ts.workout_id
GROUP BY w.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.muscle_key NOT IN ('a', 'b') THEN w.id END) = 0
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ts.muscle_key IN ('a', 'b') THEN ts.muscle_key END) = 2
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nHCyvhRR8fSEJdzsbkA35x/0).

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it using `inner join`

```
select distinct s.id
from (
  select w.id
  from workouts w
  inner join targets t on t.workout_id = w.id
  group by workout_id
  having count(1) = 2
) as s
inner join targets t on t.workout_id = s.id and t.muscle_key in ('a', 'b');
```

You can Try it from here : https://dbfiddle.uk/nPTQlhqT

Comment: This returns workout 2 even if you change id 5 from 'b' to 'e'